# calculating next business day - Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble calculating the next business day in snowflake SQL, excluding weekends and state based public holidays (not all public holidays are national in Australia).

My end goal is to adjust a service request job open date to align with the clients agreed service hours. so if a job request comes in on a weekend for example, the job is actually logged first thing monday morning contractually. Any idea what I'm missing that's making the non work days calculate incorrectly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my code so far for one of the states:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Report Date",
            CASE WHEN ACT.holiday_name      IS NULL     AND "Calendar Day in Week" IN ('Sat','Sun') THEN    "Calendar Day in Week"                      ELSE    ACT.holiday_name    END AS  "ACT Public Holiday",
            CASE WHEN "ACT Public Holiday"  IS NULL                                                 THEN    'Work Day'                                                              END AS  "ACT Work Day",
            CASE WHEN "ACT Public Holiday"  IS NOT NULL THEN LEAD("Report Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "ACT Work Day" ='Work Day' ORDER BY "Report Date") END AS  "ACT Next Work Day"

FROM            "ODS"."DWBI_DATAHUB"."V_D_CALENDAR" C
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   ACT ON  C."Report Date" =   ACT.HOLIDAY_DATE  AND (ACT.IS_ALL_NODES = 'Y' OR ACT.NODE_ID = 'ACT')
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   NSW ON  C."Report Date" =   NSW.HOLIDAY_DATE  AND (NSW.IS_ALL_NODES = 'Y' OR NSW.NODE_ID = 'NSW')
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   QLD ON  C."Report Date" =   QLD.HOLIDAY_DATE  AND (QLD.IS_ALL_NODES = 'Y' OR QLD.NODE_ID = 'QLD')
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   VIC ON  C."Report Date" =   VIC.HOLIDAY_DATE  AND (VIC.IS_ALL_NODES = 'Y' OR VIC.NODE_ID = 'VIC')
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   SA  ON  C."Report Date" =   SA.HOLIDAY_DATE   AND (SA.IS_ALL_NODES  = 'Y' OR SA.NODE_ID  = 'SA')
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   WA  ON  C."Report Date" =   WA.HOLIDAY_DATE   AND (WA.IS_ALL_NODES  = 'Y' OR WA.NODE_ID  = 'WA')
LEFT JOIN       "ODS"."ODS"."DS_ALLIANCE_HOLIDAY"   NT  ON  C."Report Date" =   NT.HOLIDAY_DATE   AND (NT.IS_ALL_NODES  = 'Y' OR NT.NODE_ID  = 'NT')
WHERE           "Report Date" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY        "Report Date"
```

[The Results I'm getting from the query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMynQ.png)

Comment: assuming `V_D_CALENDAR` is the initial report, does it have a `state` because all those table joins could be simplifed down to "all `IS_ALL_NODES`" and "all not `IS_ALL_NODES` but of the correct state", you have only block to do your logic on.

Comment: No state column in the calendar table unfortunately. hence the method I've used above to transpose the holiday table by state against the calendar table. If there's a better way I'm always open to it though. Thanks for commenting.